# WPF Image Not Loading

Tags: c#, wpf, image, caching, imagesource

I have a WPF application which has a listbox with a list of images and then an image inside a scroll container. When the user clicks an item in the listbox, it switches the image source. I'm working with really big resolution images which can be up to 10k x 10k. The application loads the first high-res image without problems, and you can even switch to images with smaller resolutions. But when you try to load a new high-res image, the image just goes blank. But when you click on the first high-res image that was previously loaded, it appears fine.

I figure its a memory/cache issue but I'm not sure what I need to do to free the memory/cache from the old image before loading the new one.

Here is how I'm setting the source:

```
String fileLocation = ... ;
ImageSourceConverter sc = new ImageSourceConverter();
img_Map.Source = (ImageSource)sc.ConvertFromString(fileLocation);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/12/17/silverlight-s-big-image-problem-and-what-you-can-do-about-it.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm not at my computer right now, but I'll play around with that tomorrow. In the mean time, any other suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: @Per. I played around with the info in that link but it didn't do anything different. I don't think it's a reference issue since I'm not handling the image directly; rather, I'm just changing the source of an image control. So I think it's a problem with how the control is handling images (not releasing previous image when the source changes). Does that sound right? Has anyone else come across this issue?

Comment: Bump... I really need some help with this one. If anyone has any ideas, I would greatly appreciate it.